# Why is this function executed twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a tree structure. [JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/1/edit?html,js,output)

in the directive

```
scope.add_child_task = function() {
    scope.add_task(scope.path,"child of " + scope.member.name);
    if (!scope.has_children) {
        scope.add_children_element();
        scope.has_children = true;
    }
};
```

in the controller

```
$scope.add_task = function(to,name) { 
    DataFactory.add_task(to,name);
};
```

The factory is finding the correct position and adding the node.

**When adding a child to nodes with existing children it's adding two children and i don't understand why.**

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I can lose `has_children` and it still produces the same result

[updated JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/7/edit?html,js,output)

Member link functin

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            

            element.append("<collection></collection>"); 
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            scope.get_path = function() { 
                var temp = scope.$parent.get_path();
                temp.push(scope.member.name);
                return temp;
            };
            scope.path = scope.get_path();

            scope.add_child_task = function() {
                scope.add_task(scope.path,"child of " + scope.member.name);
            };
        }
```

**EDIT 2**
Droped the for loops as well - just exchanging references, nothing left but a function being executed twice !

[updated JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/7/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is not the answer, but in "add_children_element()" you are calling "scope.has_children = true;", and in "add_task()" too.
Check if you haven't repeated this mistake in you DataFactory, and try to log (console.log) what the code exactly does.

Comment: I believe you want `this` inside the first function body, not `scope`

Comment: @Mark Reed - could you explain ? `this` instead of what ?

Comment: You're missing some `var` declarations, and I'm also not so sure about the `for ... in` loops in your "add_task" function.

Comment: @Pointy - please see the update. the `for` loops are your basic deep search. I know they are ugly but it's not my focus here. Thanks.

Comment: @haki well so long as you realize that `for ... in` loops are unwise for JavaScript arrays.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks for the tip - lost them too. still stuck on that function.

Comment: Have reduced the code in the JS Bin example - http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/17/edit?html,js,output - still exhibiting the problem, but may be little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling the entire element (including the part added by the directive's template, which has already been compiled):

```
element.append("<collection></collection>"); 
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Since your click handler is in the template **compiling the template a second time results in a second set of click handlers** (amongst other things) being added.

```
template: "<li>{{member.name}}" + 
      " <i>{{path}}</i> <a href ng-click='add_child_task()'>Add Child</a></li>",
```

**The Fix:** Instead use this to compile only the new element you've added:

```
newe = angular.element("<collection></collection>");
element.append(newe); 
$compile(newe)(scope);
```

[updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/19/edit)

Comment: I was staring at that jsbin for ages trying to figure out what was going on. +1.