# AngularJS ui.sortable with connected lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I  made editor using JQuery for data structure showed [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10577213), features:

- click on [X] triggers deleting parent node and all child nodes linked to this node
- click on [V] triggers showing drop-down container with child nodes and copy of parent node
- click on [x] triggers deleting child node
- user can perform drag-sorting for parent nodes (outlined with ++++)
- user can perform drag-sorting inside parent's drop-down container including copy of parent node
- etc.

I'd like to translate it to AngularJS for education purposes. I implemented parent nodes sorting, but I have a trouble implementing sorting for children nodes. Is there best approach for doing things like that w/o changing data structure?

Comment: to get you started with hierarchies in angular js, Go over this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496922/why-is-this-function-executed-twice) and see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aTOrIkIS/19/edit)

Comment: @haki, thanks, seems very useful for my task